# PHP Array Readable

Tags: php, arrays

I have an Array format.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 11
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 12
        )

)
```

It should to be changed the array format to be like this format:

```
[1,11,12];
```

Please help. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Cany you please share your try  ?

Comment: `array_column()` would help.

Comment: This looks more like a request for code rather than a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For (PHP 5 >= 5.5.0, PHP 7) you can use `array_column` and lower than that you can use `array_map` function (for PHP < 5.3) you need to define saperate function for `array_map` instead of anonymous function.

```
$array = array
(
    '0' => array
    (
        'order_id' => 1
    ),

    '1' => array
    (
        'order_id' => 11
    ),

    '2' => array
    (
        'order_id' => 12
    )

);

$new_array = array_column($array, 'order_id');
print_r($new_array);


$new_array = array_map(function($element) {
    return $element['order_id'];
}, $array);
print_r($new_array);
```

**output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 11
    [2] => 12
)
```

Comment: Thank you! It used successfully.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$arr = Array
(
    0 => Array
        (
            'order_id' => 1
        ),

    1 => Array
        (
            'order_id'=> 11
        ),

   2 => Array
        (
            'order_id' => 12
        ),

);
$newArr = array();

foreach($arr as $x){
    foreach($x as $y){
        $newArr[] = $y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$ar = array(array('order_id' => 1), array('order_id' => 11), array('order_id' => 12));

$temp = array();

foreach ($ar as $val) {
    $temp[] = $val['order_id'];
}

print_r($temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are looking to flatten the array. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1320259/393021) has some tips on how to do that. Also, there's a golf version in [this Github gist](https://gist.github.com/kohnmd/11197713#gistcomment-1677339).

For the specific case in your question, this should do

```
function specificFlatten($arr) {
    if (!is_array($arr)) return false;

    $result = [];

    foreach ($arr as $arr_1) {
        result[] = $arr_1['order_id'];
    }

    return $result;
}
```